# How to convert the Raw part to normal format from a pcap file?

Tags: python, scapy

```
>>> pkts[0].show()

###[ Ethernet ]###
dst       = 00:00:5e:00:01:32
src       = 00:01:d7:ea:ec:45
type      = IPv4
###[ IP ]###
 version   = 4L
 ihl       = 5L
 tos       = 0x0
 len       = 523
 id        = 56882
 flags     = DF
 frag      = 0L
 ttl       = 255
 proto     = udp
 chksum    = 0x8738
 src       = 221.131.232.12
 dst       = 10.212.68.18
 \options   \
###[ UDP ]###
    sport     = radius_acct
    dport     = radius_acct
    len       = 503
    chksum    = 0xdda4
###[ Raw ]###
       load      = '\x04;\x01\xefna\r\xa5\xb0w\x05\xbaU]t\x9a9k\x1c<\x01\x0fwzcna06629197\x05\x06\x01!e\x9f\x04\x06\xdd\x83\xe8\x0c\x08\x06\n\x9e\xfd\x9b\x0b\nnat-hsi1 \x1fZJWZH-MC-CMNET-BRAS12-CN_ME60(\x06\x00\x00\x00\x03)\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00*\x06$\x1d|o+\x06g\x88\xe3L,#ZJWZH-M01222175401439efd39c069285-\x06\x00\x00\x00\x01.\x06\x00\x03\xa0 /\x06\x00c\xbeC0\x06\x00\x9dq04\x06\x00\x00\x00\x005\x06\x00\x00\x00\x037\x06S\xbbGk=\x06\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x1f\x13c8:3a:35:4f:30:d8W4slot=1;subslot=2;port=22;vlanid=1439;vlanid2=1754;\x06\x06\x00\x00\x00\x02\x07\x06\x00\x00\x00\x013\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x06\x00\t:\x80\x1a\xc1\x00\x00\x07\xdb<"10.158.253.155 c8:3a:35:4f:30:d8\x03\x06\x00@\x02\xb8\x02\x06\x00@\x02\xb8\x06\x06\x00@\x02\xb8\x05\x06\x00@\x02\xb8\x16\x06\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x1a\x06\x00\x01\x0e\xa5\x8a\x08nat444T\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00=\x06\x00\x00\x00\x0f>\x06\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x90\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x91\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x92\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x93\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x95\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99\x13c8:3a:35:4f:30:d8\x9f\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x06\x01@\x00\x00M\x06\x00_\xc2\x88\xa1\x06\xb7\xf5#]\xa2\x06\x00\x004\x00\xa3\x06\x00\x00C\xff'
```

The output above is parsing from python scapy, and the [Raw] part is my concern. I need to recognize each field in [Raw] part and then modified it, anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually know which protocol is in the raw part?

Comment: It should be Radius Protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

Scapy up until [v2.3.1](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/b903c51e7e80c3b0653f1b857eae5a49b03beb4e/scapy/layers/radius.py) only had basic Radius Layers that weren't registered to scapy for automatic radius dissection based on radius ports. Skip to the end for the original answer to this question referring to `scapy<=2.3.1`.

Scapy [v2.3.2](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/layers/radius.py) comes with Radius and Radius Attribute layers that are bound to the radius ports for automatic dissection. Therefore please update scapy and try again.

```
pip install --upgrade scapy
```

Here's your data dissected with this version of scapy:

```
 Radius(data).show()
###[ Radius ]###
  code= Accounting-Request
  id= 59
  len= 495
  authenticator= 'na\r\xa5\xb0w\x05\xbaU]t\x9a9k\x1c<'
  \attributes\
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= User-Name
   |  len= 15
   |  value= 'wzcna06629197'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= NAS-Port
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\x01!e\x9f'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= NAS-IP-Address
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\xdd\x83\xe8\x0c'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Framed-IP-Address
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\n\x9e\xfd\x9b'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Filter-Id
   |  len= 10
   |  value= 'nat-hsi1'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= NAS-Identifier
   |  len= 31
   |  value= 'ZJWZH-MC-CMNET-BRAS12-CN_ME60'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Acct-Status-Type
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\x00\x00\x00\x03'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Acct-Delay-Time
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\x00\x00\x00\x00'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Acct-Input-Octets
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '$\x1d|o'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Acct-Output-Octets
   |  len= 6
   |  value= 'g\x88\xe3L'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Acct-Session-Id
   |  len= 35
   |  value= 'ZJWZH-M01222175401439efd39c069285'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Acct-Authentic
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\x00\x00\x00\x01'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Acct-Session-Time
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\x00\x03\xa0 '
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Acct-Input-Packets
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\x00c\xbeC'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Acct-Output-Packets
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\x00\x9dq0'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= 52
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\x00\x00\x00\x00'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= 53
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\x00\x00\x00\x03'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= 55
   |  len= 6
   |  value= 'S\xbbGk'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= NAS-Port-Type
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\x00\x00\x00\x0f'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Calling-Station-Id
   |  len= 19
   |  value= 'c8:3a:35:4f:30:d8'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= 87
   |  len= 52
   |  value= 'slot=1;subslot=2;port=22;vlanid=1439;vlanid2=1754;'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Service-Type
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\x00\x00\x00\x02'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Framed-Protocol
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\x00\x00\x00\x01'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Acct-Link-Count
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\x00\x00\x00\x00'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Idle-Timeout
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\x00\x00\x00\x00'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Session-Timeout
   |  len= 6
   |  value= '\x00\t:\x80'
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Vendor-Specific
   |  len= 193
   |  value= '\x00\x00\x07\xdb<"10.158.253.155 c8:3a:35:4f:30:d8\x03\x06\x00@\x02\xb8\x02\x06\x00@\x02\xb8\x06\x06\x00@\x02\xb8\x05\x06\x00@\x02\xb8\x16\x06\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x1a\x06\x00\x01\x0e\xa5\x8a\x08nat444T\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00=\x06\x00\x00\x00\x0f>\x06\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x90\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x91\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x92\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x93\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x95\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99\x13c8:3a:35:4f:30:d8\x9f\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x06\x01@\x00\x00M\x06\x00_\xc2\x88\xa1\x06\xb7\xf5#]\xa2\x06\x00\x004\x00\xa3\x06\x00\x00C\xff'
```

**original answer referring scapy <=2.3.1**

Scapy comes with basic Radius layers but it seems like they're not automatically bound to the radius port. This means you'll either have to a) manually dissect the `[Raw]` layer as `Radius()` or b) bind the radius layer to the `radius-acct` port.

```
radius-acct     1813/tcp        radacct         # Radius Accounting
radius-acct     1813/udp        radacct
```

a) to manually dissect `Raw` as `Radius`

```
 rad = Radius(pkts[0]['Raw'].load)
```

b) to bind the Radius layer to a dst port 1813 for auto-dissection:

```
 bind_layers(TCP, Radius, dport=1813)
 bind_layers(UDP, Radius, dport=1813)
```

this will result in:

```
>>> Radius(pkts[0][Raw].load).show()
###[ Radius ]###
  code= Accounting-Request
  id= 59
  len= 495
  authenticator= 'na\r\xa5\xb0w\x05\xbaU]t\x9a9k\x1c<'
###[ Raw ]###
     load= '\x01\x0fwzcna06629197\x05\x06\x01!e\x9f\x04\x06\xdd\x83\xe8\x0c\x08\x06\n\x9e\xfd\x9b\x0b\nnat-hsi1 \x1fZJWZH-MC-CMNET-BRAS12-CN_ME60(\x06\x00\x00\x00\x03)\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00*\x06$\x1d|o+\x06g\x88\xe3L,#ZJWZH-M01222175401439efd39c069285-\x06\x00\x00\x00\x01.\x06\x00\x03\xa0 /\x06\x00c\xbeC0\x06\x00\x9dq04\x06\x00\x00\x00\x005\x06\x00\x00\x00\x037\x06S\xbbGk=\x06\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x1f\x13c8:3a:35:4f:30:d8W4slot=1;subslot=2;port=22;vlanid=1439;vlanid2=1754;\x06\x06\x00\x00\x00\x02\x07\x06\x00\x00\x00\x013\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x06\x00\t:\x80\x1a\xc1\x00\x00\x07\xdb<"10.158.253.155 c8:3a:35:4f:30:d8\x03\x06\x00@\x02\xb8\x02\x06\x00@\x02\xb8\x06\x06\x00@\x02\xb8\x05\x06\x00@\x02\xb8\x16\x06\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x1a\x06\x00\x01\x0e\xa5\x8a\x08nat444T\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00=\x06\x00\x00\x00\x0f>\x06\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x90\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x91\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x92\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x93\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x95\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99\x13c8:3a:35:4f:30:d8\x9f\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x06\x01@\x00\x00M\x06\x00_\xc2\x88\xa1\x06\xb7\xf5#]\xa2\x06\x00\x004\x00\xa3\x06\x00\x00C\xff'
```

Comment: I got the same output as you did, but my request is to modify the "Attribute Value Pairs" for the Radius pcap. I guess the "load" part might be related. And now i could not modify it since i really don't  know what the load means, i think i should convert it into normal string first.

Comment: scapy's radius layer does not dissect radius attributes (rfc2866, see [1]) therefore they'll show up as a Raw layer. you'll probably have to implement this yourself.
[1] https://github.com/phaethon/scapy/blob/master/scapy/layers/radius.py

Comment: Ian, you should probably accept this answer (and upvote it), that would be nice for tintin and would help other people viewing your question. tintin maybe you could edit your answer to add the content of your comment since it is really helpful? - Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Thanks @Pierre, I've updated my answer with changes introduced by the recently released scapy 2.3.2 which comes with radius attributes layers. I've also fixed the links to point to the official scapy github repo. This should now fully answer the question.

Comment: @tintin great work! I wish I could upvote your answer twice!

Comment: I got the same output as you did while using scapy 2.3.2 with
`pcap = 'start.pcap'
pkts = rdpcap(pcap)
pkts[0].show()
`
But error occurred while using command `Radius(pkts[0]).show()`:
`return  s[self.sz:], self.m2i(pkt, struct.unpack(self.fmt, s[:self.sz])[0])
error: unpack requires a string argument of length 1`
Thanks for your great effort to let me get the parsing result. Thank you @tintin

Comment: Its `Radius(pkts[0][Raw].load).show()` otherwise it'll try to dissect the whole packet including its headers (Ether/IP/..) as Radius payload while you only want to dissect the Raw layer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote, and i'll back to here to upvote this solution once i getting to the 15.☺ Thank you @tintin

Comment: you're welcome. instead of upvoting it you could as well just accept it as the correct answer. that would help other people searching for the exact same issue. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work